# Aggregate function to count occurrences of specific word

Tags: group-by, aggregate

I have a table upon which I'm performing a GROUP BY statement. One of the columns in my table can contain one of 5 different words (essentially an enumerated type). Is there a way I can use an aggregate to get the occurrences of each enum, but display each count in a new column?

For example, given the table:

```
+---------+
|id | enum|
+---------+
| 1 | A   |
| 1 | B   |
| 1 | C   |
| 1 | A   |
+---------+
```

I'd like to get something like this after grouping by `id`:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
|id | a_count| b_count | c_count |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 1 |   2    |    1    |    1    |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Using PIVOT would be the best way to solve this, but you don't specify the specific RDBMS that you are using.  Otherwise, the solution by Balaza Papp will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, have 3 `SUM`s of the needed values converted to 1, and others to 0.

```
select
  id,
  sum(case when enum = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as a_count,
  sum(case when enum = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as b_count,
  sum(case when enum = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as c_count
from
  table
group by
  id
;
```